# How to keep last slash in directory path?

Tags: java

code:

```java
public Path getToolsDirPath() {
    return Paths.get(mainDir, "Tools/");
}
```

and setting value to string:

```
String pathToFile = getToolsDirPath() + "tool.exe"
```

I receive: the path to file

```
Main/Toolstool.exe
```

(without slash between directory TOOLS and filename tool.exe)

How to keep the last slash in this path?

Comment: return Paths.get(mainDir, "Tools\/");

Comment: Why not add `/tool.exe`?

Comment: Instead of worrying about the slash, I think you can use [`resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) to join the path and file: `Path pathToFile = getToolsDirPath().resolve("tool.exe");` https://ideone.com/WUfSIG

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Well, since you're a self-confessed comments-answerer, I copied this to answers (community wiki, i won't get rep for it). If you wish to post it yourself, I will delete it.

Comment: @Michael That's cool. I don't worry about rep. I have never used `resolve` before but was curious so I looked it up. Learned my fun fact for today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the slash, you can use [`resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) to join the path and file:

```
Path pathToFile = getToolsDirPath().resolve("tool.exe");
```

[Runnable example](https://ideone.com/WUfSIG):

```
class Ideone
{
    static String mainDir = "/home/myname/somefolder";
    public static Path getToolsDirPath()
    {
        return Paths.get(mainDir, "Tools/");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(getToolsDirPath().resolve("tool.exe"));
    }
}
```

<sub>[Original author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)</sub>